# Flutter local_notification zonedSchedule not working in the APK version

Tags: android, flutter, notifications, apk

I'm using flutter_local_notifications package in my app to send notifications to the users at a specific time. In the debug mode, everything works fine but when I build apk, it doesn't work. There is no error, no crash.

```
tz.initializeTimeZones();

      var now = DateTime.now();

      var time2 = tz.TZDateTime(
        tz.local,
        now.year,
        now.month,
        now.day,
        _selectedTime.hour,
        _selectedTime.minute,
      );

      int notificationID = widget.newActivity.id;

      _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
          .zonedSchedule(
              notificationID, title, body, time2, generalNotificationDetails,
              uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
                  UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
              androidAllowWhileIdle: true)
          .then((value) {
        _setAlarm(widget.newActivity.id, _formattedTime);
        setState(() {
          _hasNotification = true;
        });
        print("notification created!");
      });
```

Comment: Did you get that? @draxex

Comment: Yes, I've fixed that. The problem is when I use it on the real device, the code couldn't get properly my device's timezone, so the notification couldn't set. The solution is using the flutter_native_timezone package. I get the device timezone through flutter_navite_timezone package and implement it when I set the notification time. @FathahKodag